# Python Unittest, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, pycharm

Начинающий.
Не могу сообразить в чем проблема.
При запуске тестов в RUN выдает ошибку.
При запуске в режиме DEBUG ошибки нет.
Подскажите куда копать?
[image: Поведение при запуске RUN]

[image: Поведение при запуске DEBUG]

UPD. 02.10.18

[image: RUN/DEBUG Configuration]

Comment: RUN и DEBUG конфигурацию прикрепите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @nick_gabpe Добавил

Comment: Не очень похоже на корректную ран конфигурацию, здесь класс `TableTest1` фигурирует в target. Попробуй удалить все эти временные конфигурации и запустить тесты по правому клику еще раз.